# Remove some properties after inner Join in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I want to join two featureCollections and remove the ID field in order to run linearRegression in GEE. I found codes to clean the featureCollection after innerJoin, and snippet to remove properties from FC. However, when I try on my own data, all the properties from FC were removed!

[Here is my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/yuanMSU/MG_Kaz)

```
// Create the primary collection.
var primaryFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {foo: 0, label: 'a'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {foo: 1, label: 'b'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {foo: 1, label: 'c'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {foo: 2, label: 'd'}),
]);

print('primary fc',primaryFeatures);

// Create the secondary collection.
var secondaryFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {bar: 1, label: 'e'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {bar: 1, label: 'f'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {bar: 2, label: 'g'}),
  ee.Feature(null, {bar: 3, label: 'h'}),
]);

print('2nd fc',secondaryFeatures);

// Use an equals filter to specify how the collections match.
var toyFilter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'foo',
  rightField: 'bar'
});

// Define the join.
var innerJoin = ee.Join.inner('primary', 'secondary');

// Apply the join.
var toyJoin = innerJoin.apply(primaryFeatures, secondaryFeatures, toyFilter);

// Print the result.
print('Inner join toy example:', toyJoin);

// I tried 
// clean the join
// this snippet is from stackexchange 
function cleanJoin(feature){
  return ee.Feature(feature.get('primary')).copyProperties(feature.get('secondary'));
}
var Joined = toyJoin.map(cleanJoin);
print('joined',Joined)

// remove one properties
// this snippet is also from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321724/removing-property-from-feature-or-featurecollection-using-google-earth-engine

var removeProperty = function(feat, property) {
  var properties = feat.propertyNames()
  print(properties);
  var selectProperties = properties.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', property))
  return feat.select(selectProperties)
}

var removeJoined = removeProperty(Joined,'foo');
print('remove joined',removeJoined) // all properties were removed!!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var removeProperty = function(feat, property) {
  var properties = feat.propertyNames()
  print(properties);
  var selectProperties = properties.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', property))
  return feat.select(selectProperties)
}
```

This does not work for what you want because `.propertyNames()` returns the names of properties *of the collection*, not its elements — since this collection has no properties, it removes every property. This function was intended to work on a feature, not a collection; you need to `map` it over the collection.

However, it's also unnecessarily complicated. The simplest way to remove properties is to `set` them to `null`:

```js
var removeJoined = Joined.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.set('foo', null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kevin@Keven Reid! It works. Thanks for the clarification as well!